# Even After Enabling the Billing Account, I am still getting "Status: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" while using google maps places api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-console-developer

[billing information that it is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbqb0.jpg)

I have enabled billing, but after using for a very few time and making very few requests I am getting:

> You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account  For more information on usage limits and the Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage"

> [react-places-autocomplete]: error happened when fetching data from Google Maps API.
>   Please check the docs here (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses)
>   Status:  OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Can someone please help to how to get rid of this problem?

I am using React js and my script code in public/index.html is

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE&libraries=places"></script>
```

actually in the place of MY_KEY_HERE i am using the key i have generated and it worked super fine for 1 hr and later it is showing this error

and also my code for selecting places is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Toper3 from './Toper3';
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBBtn, MDBInput,MDBCard, MDBCardBody } from 'mdbreact'; 
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PlacesAutocomplete, { geocodeByAddress, geocodeByPlaceId, getLatLng } from 'react-places-autocomplete';
import TimeField from 'react-simple-timefield';

const isObject = val => {
    return typeof val === 'object' && val !== null;
  };

  const classnames = (...args) => {
    const classes = [];
    args.forEach(arg => {
      if (typeof arg === 'string') {
        classes.push(arg);
      } else if (isObject(arg)) {
        Object.keys(arg).forEach(key => {
          if (arg[key]) {
            classes.push(key);
          }
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error(
          '`classnames` only accepts string or object as arguments'
        );
      }
    });

    return classes.join(' ');
  };


class FindaRide extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            info : [],
            source: '',
            post_address_obj: {},
            errorMessage: '',
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            isGeocoding: false,   
            d_post_address_obj: {},
            d_errorMessage: '',
            d_latitude: null,
            d_longitude: null,
            d_isGeocoding: false,                      
            destination : ''
        }
        }
        handleSourceAddressChange = address => {
            // console.log(address);
            this.setState({
              source: address,
              latitude: null,
              longitude: null,
              errorMessage: ""
            });
          };
          handleDestinationAddressChange = address => {
            // console.log(address);
            this.setState({
              destination: address,
              d_latitude: null,
              d_longitude: null,
              d_errorMessage: ""
            });
          }; 
          refine(){
              alert("refinement");
              const result = this.state.info.filter(word => word.source ==this.state.source&&word.destination==this.state.destination);
              console.log("filtered "+result.length);
              this.props.history.push({pathname : `findlist`, state : {details : this.props.location.state.details,info : this.state.info}}); 

          }
          handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api2/')
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({
                    info : res.data
                });
                //console.log(res.data);
                this.refine();

            })                
        }            
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Toper3 >{this.props.location.state.details.firstname} {this.props.location.state.details.lastname}</Toper3>
                <br/>              
                <MDBContainer>
                <MDBRow>

                <MDBCol md="6" className="mb-4"  > {/*style={{ maxWidth: "22rem" }}*/}
                <MDBCard color="indigo" text="white" className="text-center" align="center" style={{ maxWidth: "22rem" }}>
                    <MDBCardBody align = "center" >
                            FILL IN THE DETAILS TO FIND A RIDE
                    </MDBCardBody>
                </MDBCard> 
                </MDBCol>   
                </MDBRow> 
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <MDBRow>
                    <MDBCol md="6" className="mb-4">

                    <label> Source </label>

                    <PlacesAutocomplete
                    value={this.state.source}
                    onChange={this.handleSourceAddressChange}
                    >
                    {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps }) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="Demo__search-bar-container">
                        <div className="Demo__search-input-container">
                            <input
                            {...getInputProps({
                                placeholder: "Tag the location",
                                className: "Demo__search-input"
                            })}
                            />
                            {this.state.source.length > 0 && (
                            <button
                                className="Demo__clear-button"
                                onClick={this.handleCloseClick}
                            >
                                x
                            </button>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        {suggestions.length > 0 && (
                            <div className="Demo__autocomplete-container">
                            {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                                const className = classnames("Demo__suggestion-item", {
                                "Demo__suggestion-item--active": suggestion.active
                                });

                                return (
                                /* eslint-disable react/jsx-key */
                                <div
                                    {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                                    className
                                    })}
                                >
                                    <strong>
                                    {suggestion.formattedSuggestion.mainText}
                                    </strong>{" "}
                                    <small>
                                    {suggestion.formattedSuggestion.secondaryText}
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                                );
                                /* eslint-enable react/jsx-key */
                            })}
                            <div className="Demo__dropdown-footer">
                                <div>
                                <img
                                    src="http://files.hostgator.co.in/hostgator254362/image/powered-by-google.png"
                                    className="Demo__dropdown-footer-image"
                                />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        )}
                        </div>
                    );
                    }}
                </PlacesAutocomplete>
                </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
                <MDBRow>
                <MDBCol md="6" className="mb-4">
                <MDBInput
                label="SOURCE"
                group
                type="text"
                validate
                error="wrong"
                success="right"
                value = {this.state.source}
                style={{ maxWidth: "18rem" }}
                //icon="envelope"
                required
                />      
                </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>                  
                <MDBRow>
                    <MDBCol md="6" className="mb-4">

                    <label> Destination </label>

                    <PlacesAutocomplete
                    value={this.state.destination}
                    onChange={this.handleDestinationAddressChange}
                    >
                    {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps }) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="Demo__search-bar-container">
                        <div className="Demo__search-input-container">
                            <input
                            {...getInputProps({
                                placeholder: "Tag the location",
                                className: "Demo__search-input"
                            })}
                            />
                            {this.state.destination.length > 0 && (
                            <button
                                className="Demo__clear-button"
                                onClick={this.handleCloseClick}
                            >
                                x
                            </button>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        {suggestions.length > 0 && (
                            <div className="Demo__autocomplete-container">
                            {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                                const className = classnames("Demo__suggestion-item", {
                                "Demo__suggestion-item--active": suggestion.active
                                });

                                return (
                                /* eslint-disable react/jsx-key */
                                <div
                                    {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                                    className
                                    })}
                                >
                                    <strong>
                                    {suggestion.formattedSuggestion.mainText}
                                    </strong>{" "}
                                    <small>
                                    {suggestion.formattedSuggestion.secondaryText}
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                                );
                                /* eslint-enable react/jsx-key */
                            })}
                            <div className="Demo__dropdown-footer">
                                <div>
                                <img
                                    src="http://files.hostgator.co.in/hostgator254362/image/powered-by-google.png"
                                    className="Demo__dropdown-footer-image"
                                />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        )}
                        </div>
                    );
                    }}
                </PlacesAutocomplete>
                </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>

                 <MDBRow>
                <MDBCol md="6" className="mb-4">
                <MDBInput
                label="DESTINATION"
                group
                type="text"
                validate
                error="wrong"
                success="right"
                value = {this.state.destination}
                style={{ maxWidth: "18rem" }}
                //icon="envelope"
                required
                />      
                </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>                          
                <br/>
                <br/>                                                         
                <MDBRow>  
                <MDBCol md="4" className="mb-4">                   

                <label> DateofJourney </label>    
                <input type = "date" value = {this.state.date} onChange={this.handledatechange} />  {/*(onChange = {event => this.setState({date:event.target.value})} required*/}
                </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow> 

                <MDBRow>
                <MDBCol md="6" className="mb-4">
                <MDBInput
                label="anything to say"
                group
                type="text"
                validate
                error="wrong"
                success="right"
                value = {this.state.ats} onChange={this.handleatschange}
                style={{ maxWidth: "18rem" }}
                icon="envelope"
                required
                />      
                </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>                                                              
                    <MDBRow>  
                    <MDBCol md="6" className="mb-4">                   
                    <Fragment>

                    <MDBBtn gradient="blue" type="submit">Submit</MDBBtn>
                    </Fragment>  
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow> 
                </form>
                </MDBContainer>                    
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FindaRide;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbqb0.jpg) you provided, it seems that your Billing Account is based in India.

As you might be aware, Google Maps Platform [pay as you go pricing has been launched](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-migration) in India last Nov. 18, 2019. Before this change, your project was subjected to some free limits which may cause OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors when exceeded.

> To fix this issue, you will need to create a new billing account
>   dedicated for Maps APIs only and migrate your maps projects to this
>   new account.

Here's a [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq#bill-how) that you could follow to learn how to create a new billing account for Maps. Kindly make sure to select the correct business the billing account will pay for (in this case ***Google Maps Platform***).

Below that is also the section that would help you learn how to [migrate your projects](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq#bill-mig).

If you still need help with this issue, I would suggest that you [file a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case) with us on the GCP Console to open a personalized communication channel as this question does not appear to be about programming.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have waited for till 1 30 pm (Indian time) and the quota got refreshed .. And now its working fine.. so the answer is just wait upto "Pacific mid night time" and then start working again peacefully (note that ur billing account should be enabled )

Comment: i am waiting still 3 days. still i am getting "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"